# HTML tag stored in ModelMap not interpreted as HTML by the browser

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jstl, html4

I have a spring controller with the following code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMessage.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
protected String uploadFile(ModelMap model){

     //... other codes

    model.addAttribute("theMessage", "Hello world <b>how are you</b> today?");

    return "the-view";
}
```

In the client side (JavaScript), I show this message using the following code :

```
document.getElementById('theMessageSpan').innerHTML = '<c:out value="${theMessage}"/>';
```

But when it is displayed, it shows a string literal

`Hello world <b>how are you</b> today?`

I need to show the message as :

`Hello world` **how are you** `today?`

I tried using apache commons' `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` before putting the text in the `ModelMap`, but the result is just the same.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe by default `<c:out>` escapes XML. You'll need to explicitly tell it not to with

```
<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${theMessage}"/>
```

Can't find newer docs, but see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html). Among the attributes, you have

> **escapeXml**
>
> Determines whether characters <,>,&,'," in the resulting
> string should be converted to their corresponding character entity
> codes. Default value is true.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Problem solved. Thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just skip using `c:out`. Eg. `...innerHTML = '${theMessage}';` The JSTL bracket notation does not escape XML by default like `c:out`. In fact, I think that is the biggest difference between the two. If you aren't escaping XML, make sure you are at least sanitizing the data in some way if it is user input.